# Zabbix - Create a trigger and make sure it doesn't resolve ever

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

Title: Zabbix - Create a trigger and make sure it always stays in problem state.

Any suggestion on creating a trigger that always stays in problem state?

I have a trigger with 4 expression and I want to add a 5th eventlog type trigger expression that is always in problem state

This is because in actions I have trigger.key1-4 displayed in email. But I want to add a 5th key that has the eventlog information if it has collected data, if not then the trigger alert email will have only 4 key values.

The 4 expression will trigger the alert, 5th expression just needs to be there so I could include its value to the email.

I wonder if its possible to do with nodata for eventlog item type.

I could try

```
 {test Template:eventlog[Application,.*2176.*,Information,,^23$].last()}<>0
```

but the whole trigger will become not supported when there is no data for just eventlog item.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround

```
{test Template:eventlog[Application,.*2176.*,Information,,^23$].str(something_that_doesn't_exists)}=0
```

now the trigger always stays in problem state